# Pipeline shell step and environment variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run a shell command in a `sh` step, that depends on some environment variables. Now I know that there is the environment directive. If I declare all environment variables there, the command works just fine.

However, I have several pipeline scripts that all run this command with the same environment variables. So instead of declaring these variables in each script, I want to declare them only once. I tried to set environment variables for the jenkins user, in which I didn't succeed. Finally I declared them system wide (in /etc/environment) only to find, that they're still not present for the command run in the shell step.

I conclude from this that jenkins runs shell step commands in a clean environment, ignoring variables I may have declared. My question is now: how can I set environment variables for the shell step for all pipeline scripts in jenkins?

Comment: Have you tried adding global environment variables in Jenkins under "/configure" itself?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.